# js,css: after click on collapse-button, colapsed element showing, just on moment, after that in elemnt.style value height is empty

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, mdbootstrap

here is my code.

```html
<!-- Collapse buttons -->
<div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample"
       aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> Link with
        href </a>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="collapseExample"> Button with data-target
    </button>
</div>
<!-- / Collapse buttons -->
<!-- Collapsible element -->
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="mt-3"> Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high
        life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
        craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
    </div>
</div>
<!-- / Collapsible element -->
```

it's code from Material Bootstrap Design. i use jquery 3.5.1 and bootsrap 4.5.0 which were download with mdb install package.

Comment: here is i gif: https://ibb.co/RBjkXJB

Comment: How you are adding Height value. Are you setting this using Js?

Comment: @KetanVekariya no, it do bootstrap or jquery. it's not i'm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somwhere was additional bootstrap export